# Is there any way of customizing the recording time on PyAudio?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, speech-recognition, pyaudio, pynput

I was trying to create an instant typist of sorts. It is supposed to type what I am saying after I say it. I am trying to set the recording speed as a variable, so that you can enter a number in seconds for how long the recording will be. I need to use it for both English and Arabic.

```py
    import time
    import speech_recognition as sr
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
    keyboard = Controller()
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    lang = input('Choose a Language: \na.  Arabic \nb.  English \nAnswer: ')
    if lang == 'a' or lang == 'Arabic' or lang == 'arabic' or lang == 'A':
        with mic as source:
            print('Say Something')
            audio = r.listen(source)
            r.recognize_google(audio, language='ar-EG')
            print('That is enough')
    print('Text: ' + r.recognize_google(audio, language='ar-EG'))
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Ready!')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Go!')
    keyboard.type(r.recognize_google(audio, language='ar-EG'))
    if lang == 'b' or lang == 'English' or lang == 'english' or lang == 'B':
    with mic as source:
        print('Say Something')
        audio = r.listen(source)
        r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('That is enough')
    print('Text: ' + r.recognize_google(audio))
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Ready!')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Go!')
    keyboard.type(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Comment: You need to do some research on this topic. Personally, I would just program a system where it stops listening once the user stops speaking. Its easier and probably going to make your program better in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [streaming speech recognition](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) with google API,
not the broken speech recognition package

There are also open source libraries that support streaming but I'm not allowed to mention them here ;)

Comment: Google streaming speech recognition API is paid